# Most efficient way of dealing with multiple functions that have the same signature but different parameters

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, overloading

Currently I have multiple functions that have the same signature but do different things when called base:

```
func drawPath(from: JMapDestination, to: JMapDestination) {
    guard let fromWaypoint = navigationManager.getWaypointForDestination(destination: from),
        let toWaypoint = navigationManager.getWaypointForDestination(destination: to) else {
            return
    }

    drawPath(from: fromWaypoint, to: toWaypoint)
}


func drawPathFrom(_ from: CGPoint, to: JMapDestination) {
    guard let fromWaypoint = getWaypointForPoint(point: from),
        let toWaypoint = navigationManager.getWaypointForDestination(destination: to) else {
            return
    }

    drawPath(from: fromWaypoint, to: toWaypoint)
}



func drawPath(from: CGPoint, to: JMapWaypoint) {
    guard let fromWaypoint = getWaypointForPoint(point: from) else { return }
    drawPath(from: fromWaypoint, to: to)
}
```

I decide to create an enum and one master function using switch statements to handle the different cases:

```
enum pathType {
    case jMapWaypoint
    case jMapDestination
    case cgPoint
}


func drawPath(pathType: pathType, fromJMap: JMapWaypoint?, toJMap: JMapWaypoint?, fromJDestination: JMapDestination?, toJDestination: JMapDestination?, fromCGPoint: CGPoint?) {

    switch pathType {

    case .jMapWaypoint:
        guard let mapController = viewModel?.mapController else {
            return
        }

        let pathStyle = setPathStyle(style: JMapStyle.init())
        if let from = fromJMap, let to = toJMap {
            checkPathsBetweenWaypoints(mapController: mapController, pathStyle: pathStyle, from: from, to: to)
        }
        if let currentMap = mapController.currentMap {
            mapController.zoomToPath(on: currentMap, withPadding: 100, withAnimationDuration: 1)
        }

    case .jMapDestination:
        if let from = fromJDestination, let to = toJDestination {
            guard let fromWaypoint = getWaypointForDestination(destination: from),
                let toWaypoint = getWaypointForDestination(destination: to) else {
                    return
            }
            drawPath(pathType: .jMapWaypoint, fromJMap: fromWaypoint, toJMap: toWaypoint, fromJDestination: nil, toJDestination: nil, fromCGPoint: nil)
        }

    case .cgPoint:
        if let from = fromCGPoint, let to = toJMap {
            guard let fromWaypoint = getWaypointForPoint(point: from) else { return }
            drawPath(pathType: .jMapWaypoint, fromJMap: fromWaypoint, toJMap: to, fromJDestination: nil, toJDestination: nil, fromCGPoint: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

the function with the switch statement is working but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner, more efficient way of doing this? FYI all the functions are on the same viewController, I was thinking protocols but how would be able to do it if the protocol function signature is the same (ie drawPath) but with different parameter?

Comment: do you have a method which also accepts `JMapWaypoint ` as a from and to params?

Comment: @Harsh I do, I didn't include it in the post because the function is very big

Comment: There’s nothing inefficient here but it is terrible coding style. Secret messages to yourself based on types are a very bad idea. Say what you mean, is my advice.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner version (IMHO) would be an struct containing your path beginning and end, like:

```swift
struct MyPath {

    var start: JMapWaypoint
    var end: JMapWaypoint

    init(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint)
    {
        //Your logic here
    }
    init(start: JMapWaypoint, end: JMapWaypoint)
    {
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    }
    init(start: JMapDestination, end: JMapDestination)
    {
        //Your logic here
    }
}
```

Then you can simply init this object with whichever type you want, get the final desired type and draw your path with this object instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its the right way ... for a matter of convenience what I would have done is created extensions for `CGPoint` and `JMapDestination` which would have a method of converting this to `JMapWaypoint` called `func asWaypoint`. Finally I would use the extension method to just call the final method rather than jumping through so many hoops.

Example:

```
extension CGPoint {
   func asWaypoint() -> JMapWaypoint {
      // your logic for the conversion 
   }
}
```

And then just call the final method as 
`drawPath(from: from.asWaypoint(), to: to.asWaypoint())`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thats an interesting way of doing it, I'll give it a try